# __CLASS__ PHP. Need a clarification on this one.

Tags: php, constants

```
class foo {
  const bar1 = 10.0;
  const bar2 = 2.22;
  const bar3 = 5.12;

    function getTotal($some_string, $some_number) {
      $total = 0.0;
      // Why would this flag a warning? 
      // $what_is_const = constant("bar" . $some_string);            // DOES NOT WORK!
      $what_is_const = constant(__CLASS__ . "::bar" . $some_string); // WORKS!
      $total += $what_is_const * $some_number;  
    } 
}
```

> Warning: constant(): Couldn't find constant //with that exact same name!

Question is: why do I need to identify the class name to access the constant;
is it a matter of scoping or something?

Comment: Yes, its a [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php).

Comment: Yes, but why does it behave as such?

Comment: Because you've declared it as such.

Comment: does that mean if it's a class const, in order to access bar1 I have to explicitly state `constant("foo::bar1");` as compared to `constant("bar1"); // that is if bar1!=const` ?

Answer (score 0):

> ...is it a matter of scoping or something?

You nailed it!
As you've defined an local constant (inside class) it's is a [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php).

In order to access the class constant you ought to prepend either a class name (when referencing outside class) or via [self, static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) keywords, like this:

```
class Foo {
   const BAR = 1;

   function getBar() { return self::BAR; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constant outside of a class, it will behave as a constant outside a class. If you declare a constant inside a class, it's almost like a static property and is accessible in a very similar way (e.g., `self::MY_CONSTANT` within the class or `Foo::MY_CONSTANT` outside the class; compare to `self::$staticProperty` or `Foo::$staticProperty`).

This helps for figuring out what classes are used as dependencies, and where the constant is actually defined. That, and it generally allows for constants to be more readable as it gives contextual clues to what the constant is related to.

As an aside, it's good style to have constants be fully uppercase with underscores (e.g., `MY_CONSTANT` instead of `myConstant`). Also, class names are usually referenced as upper camel case (`MyClass` instead of `myclass`).

Comment: contextual clues, got it!